# OpenXML copy one docx into other

Tags: c#, openxml

I need fill bookmark by text from other docx file. At the same time, it is necessary to preserve the style of the text.
The structure in which I need to insert the text is something like this

```
<p>
  <r>
  <bookmartstart id=1>
    <bookmarkstart id=2>
       <r>
    <bookmartend id=2>
  <bookmarkend id=1>
```

I need replace bookmark id=2
How can this be done?

Comment: What have you tried? Kindly share your code and tell us where exactly are you stuck?